# jrxml does not compiling

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Hi i have problem in jasper reports.. im executing jrxml through my java class shown below

```
String jrxmlPath = context.getRealPath("//IREPORT_JRXML//" + reportPath);
System.out.println("in BTO report Selected  " +jasperReport);         ---->(1)
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlPath);
System.out.println("in BTO report compiled  " +jasperReport);         ----->(2)
```

"//IREPORT_JRXML// is the path where i put jrxml file. i executed my application control is executing up to ---->(1) line but it doesnt executing belo statements,here the problem is at lest i doesnt showing any error on console.

im using IReport 4.0.2,tomcat 7,jdk 1.7 , i added jasperreport-3.7.4.jar file in lib folder.

is there any issue about version problems? IReport 4.0.2,tomcat 7,jdk 1.7 and web dynamic Module 3.0 
 i tried to find out the problem unfortunately i missed some library... but i dint remember which library it is ... jasper compiler doesnt executing report design elements,report without design elements is executing , can anybody tell me wat library / jar i need to add for executing report design elements.....

Comment: it doesn't showing any error

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

```
`ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        String reportPath = context
                .getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/filname.jasper");
JasperReport jasperReport =
             JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath);`
```

Comment: im using jsf ,if i use ServletContext context = getServletContext(); this it showing error at getServletContext()